# Rename Project Name in MyEclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, myeclipse

[image]I have imported a project in myeclipse. This project a java web project developed in struts. The name of the project is NI-PROJECT. I deploy this project in tomcat6. The deployment location of the project is

```
D:\apache-tomcat-6\apache-tomcat-6.0.37\webapps\NI-PROJECT
```

I want to change the deployment location to like this

```
D:\apache-tomcat-6\apache-tomcat-6.0.37\webapps\PROJECT
```

What i do i refactor the project name to this "PROJECT" and remove the previous deployment. Now when i am going to deploy this project the location of the deployment still same which is this

```
D:\apache-tomcat-6\apache-tomcat-6.0.37\webapps\NI-PROJECT
```

did I missing something. Please guide me.

Comment: mention web root folder as your projects "WebContent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved by changing the name of project in .project file and changing context-root in .mymetadta. After that i have to just restart the myeclipse.

Answer (score 2):

in **MyEclipse**

1. right click on the project
2. Click on properties
3. type text filter as web & click on it
4. change web context root.

Comment: when i am going to do this i got following error " Web-root must be a folder."

Comment: mention web root folder as "WebContent"

Comment: No. its say i have to remove the web project capabilities but i am unable to remove that. my eclipse didn't give me permission to remove web project capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Check the file named ".project" in your MyEclipse folder.